# What is a good alternate for "forensic" in a non-criminal sense?

Tags: single-word-requests, synonyms

I was looking for a word that captured the sense of "forensic" with regard to after-the-fact "scientific methods and techniques to the investigation of crime", but in non-criminal situations.

I'm thinking primarily about root cause analysis-type scenarios in engineering and project management.

Example usage: "Can we set aside time to forensically look at the reason for all of the delays"

The implication that I would like to have is that:

1. We are doing research, as opposed to pontificating
2. The approach is data driven as opposed to philosophical

Comment: What type of non-criminal situations?

Comment: Context and an example used in a sentence would be helpful.

Comment: "Analytic" may work; it just means 'taking apart' in Greek, and that's what forensic anything does.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Deductive_reasoning

Comment: *Forensic science*.

Comment: Forensics doesn't imply criminalistics. Anyhow, consider [Reverse engineering](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reverse_engineering).

Comment: How about scientific?

Answer (score 3):

Forensic don't always means criminal things...

Forensic accounting → Administrative investigation
Forensic analisys → Informatic investigation

Maybe these are helpful for you, too:
Medical investigation, Medical jurisprudence, etc...

Comment: Thanks for those suggestions.  For "forensic accounting" the web definition is "the use of accounting skills to investigate fraud or embezzlement and to analyze financial information for use in legal proceedings."  So again, the framing of the word is within the context of a legal system.